# Dynamically created slick queries

Tags: scala, slick

I have three tables: users, groups and users_groups. There is a many to many relation from groups and users because one user can belong in multiple groups and a group is constituted by multiple users.

I have a GET query like /group?name=X&user=Y

From that I'm searching from groups with name like X, but the tricky part is searching for the groups which the Y user doesnt belong.

```
def findUserGroups(id: Long) = {
   users_groups.filter(ug => ug.userID === id)
}
```

From that I get all the groups which the user belongs, then I do this

```
var queries : List[Query[GroupsTable, GroupsTable#TableElementType, Seq]]= List[Query[GroupsTable, GroupsTable#TableElementType, Seq]]()
userGroups map { userGroup =>    
    val query : Query[GroupsTable, GroupsTable#TableElementType, Seq] = groups.filter(_.id =!= userGroup.group.get)
    queries = query :: queries
}
```

If I println userGroup it gives me the correct groups.

Finally I've been trying a union

```
def findGroupByNameSynthFunction(name: String, queries: List[Query[GroupsTable, GroupsTable#TableElementType, Seq]]) = {
    val query1 = groups.filter(g => g.name like ("%" + name + "%"))
    val unionQuery: Query[GroupsTable, GroupsTable#TableElementType, Seq] = query1
    queries map { query =>
       unionQuery ++ query
    }
    unionQuery
}
```

I execute it

```
val found = GroupsTable.findGroupByNameSynthFunction(name, queries).run
```

But I get all groups anyway.

Can Someone explained me what I'm doing very wrong!? :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where exactly you had the wrong expectation, but it probably revolves around the expression

```
queries map { query =>
   unionQuery ++ query
}
```

This doesn't have any side-effect. Unless you are doing something with the resulting value (and you are not) this doesn't do anything. You probably want something like

```
def findGroupByNameSynthFunction(
    name: String,
    queries: List[Query[GroupsTable, GroupsTable#TableElementType, Seq]]
) = queries.map(_.filter(_.name like ("%" + name + "%")))
           .reduce(_ union _)
```